# What are the functions of the components of a probability space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Earlier I had elementary courses in calculus, elementary real analysis and basic probability theory but now I am stepping towards measure theoretic probability. I knew the term 'Probability space' back in undergraduate years but now I feel I need to understand the probability space and the functions of its component-triple in measure theoretic settings.

In the elementary course the notion of the probability space was introduced. But now, I am having trouble in understanding how the components $\Omega, \mathcal{E}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ (which we write as a triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{E}, \mathbb{P})$) of the probability space $\mathfrak{P}$ works. I am highlighting the parts that make me confused in the introductory chapter of measure theoretic probability.

> a. Why do we define the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ as getting mapped from the sigma algebra $\mathcal{E}$ to the real line $\mathbb{R}$, whereas it actually gets mapped to $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$. Though the cardinality of $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is same and they are cardinally equivalent. Is this the reason, for which we use the definition of probability measure $\mathbb{P} : \mathcal{E} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

> b. I did not see the notion of 'favorable cases' in class or books (that are used in this course). How do we define it in a measure-theoretic setting?

I want to have a clear picture of the 'functions' that a probability space performs. Understanding these two points may make the understanding regarding the probability space clear. Any help, comments, suggestions and explanations in this regard are welcome, appreciated and highly valuable.

**

The texts that are used in this course: [Prof. Grimmett & Stirzaker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198847599) and [Dr. A. Klenke](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3030564010)

.

Comment: What the hell is $\mathfrak{P}$ doing in $(a)$? What does "$\Omega\to A$ for a 'good' set $A$" mean? In what sense is $(\Omega,\mathcal{E},\Bbb P)$ an *element* of $\mathfrak{P}$?

Comment: We consider *probability* measures to be valued in $[0,1]$ because we like the intuition and convenience of $P(\Omega)=1$ (and (b) bounded / finite measures are easier to work with than unbounded ones). We would not want to let $\Bbb P$ be valued in $\Bbb R$

Comment: @FShrike using the notation $\mathfrak{P}$ as the probability space with its component-triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{E}, \mathbb{P})$.
A good set is a measurable set.

Comment: I think FShrike’s gripe is that your notation really does not make sense, similarly for much of your language. @TopoSet32

Comment: @AndrewZhang I tried to edit my texts and make my questions meaningful. Please kindly let me know if my questions now make sense. And the notations I am using is used in our class and notes. Please feel free to point out anywhere I am wrong.

Comment: @TopoSet32 : Your sentence "In class we are taught that $\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$" does not make sense.  I think you are trying to talk about a random variable $X$, which is defined as a measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Also, your sentence "$\Omega$ itself does not have a mapping to any other space" does not make sense. It sounds like you are inserting unusual and unnecessary complications into probability theory.

Comment: @Michael "$\Omega$ itself does not have a mapping to any other space " - this line i copied from my class-note to verify if it was true. Also, i have not yet studied r.vs in measure-theoretic setting, (though i know rv from the viewpoint of undergrad elementary probability theory).. may I ask how did my question referring to  random variable topic? I need to fix the flaws in my understanding in probability theory, that is why i am asking.

Comment: Well that sentence is meaningless to me, perhaps you copied it out of context. Also, what do you mean by "we are taught that $\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$"? What is the arrow doing?  Are you familiar with the structure $f:A\rightarrow B$ to specify the domain and target set of a function? That seems to be the closest match to your unusual statement "we are taught that $\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$."

Comment: I am familiar with the structure of $f$ that you have written, and now I understand why you were mentioning about random variable. The arrow sign is used to denote mapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147553/discussion-between-toposet32-and-michael).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A probability space is a triplet $(\Omega, \mathcal{E},P)$ where:

- $\Omega$ is a nonempty set
- $\mathcal{E}$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$
- $P:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function that satisfies the three axioms of probability.

The elements of $\Omega$ are called *outcomes*. The elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are called *events*. The function $P$ is called a *probability measure*.

[I would not use the symbol $\mathfrak{P}$ for anything since it seems scary and overly complicated.]

---

On your questions:

a) While we can equally view a probability measure as a function $P:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ or a function $P:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow [0,1]$, the first is useful because the 3 axioms of probability traditionally include $P[A]\geq 0$ for all $A \in \mathcal{E}$ (this axiom would be redundant if we used $P:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow[0,1]$). Also, the three axioms can be used to prove the lemma $P[A]\leq 1$ for all $A \in \mathcal{E}$. So there is no need to *assume* probabilities are less than or equal to 1 when we can *prove* they are.

b) I do not know what you mean by "Since we have a probability space, where $\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$."  The closest match looks like you are talking about a random variable $X$, defined as a measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

One thing about random variables is that you can talk about their distribution without knowing the underlying sample space $\Omega$. So people do sometimes say that, if you only care about the single random variable $X$, it is sufficient to imagine that the sample space is just the set of real numbers, and the random variable is just the identity mapping, with a distribution determined by the CDF of the random variable. This is not a necessary concept, so if you do not know what this paragraph means, do not worry about it.

c) I do not know what you mean by "favorable case." That is not a standard term and it likely only has specific meaning within the context of your book or course.

Comment: By "favorable case" I mean the number of outcomes which result in the happening of the desired event .. the notion that we use in classical probability theory. I was asking if there is any similar notion used in measure-theoretic probability.

+1 for the elaborated answer.

Comment: It sounds like you are using "favorable case" as a synonym for "event." To avoid confusion I would just use the term "event." An event is a subset of $\Omega$ that is included in the sigma algebra $\mathcal{E}$. Every event $A$ has a probability $P[A]$. If $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$ that is not in $\mathcal{E}$ then $P[A]$ does not exist, we could say that $A$ is a "nonmeasurable set" with respect to the probability measure.

Comment: Thank you very much for this last comment. It is now very helpful for me. Thank you again.